# Convert one digit day month to 2 digit with toISOString javascript

Tags: javascript, date

Hi there I would like to convert 'YYYY-M-D' to 'YYYY-MM-DD' with   toISOString but when I set one digit `DAy` it's not quite correct return value.

```
const date = new Date('1991-1-1').toISOString().substr(0, 10);
//"1990-12-31"
```

or

```
const date = new Date('1991-01-01').toISOString().substr(0, 10);

//"1990-12-31"
```

But I would like to have "1990-01-01",
I know that I can use some getMonth and so on, I looking for a native solution and simple one. Thanks

Comment: The second one should work. The *only* way I can get the `1990-12-31` output is if I try this first code in Edge. The second piece of code works in Chrome, Firefox, Edge, and IE11 for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"1991-1-1" is not a format supported by ECMAScript so parsing is implementation dependent, it might be parsed as UTC, local or treated as an invalid date. `new Date('1991-1-1')` returns an invalid date in Safari at least.

If you just want to add a leading zero to single digit numbers, do that and avoid the vagaries of the built–in parser:

```js
// Using split + join
console.log(
  '1991-1-1'.split('-').map(c => (c<10?'0':'') + +c).join('-')
);

// Using replace
console.log(
  '1991-1-1'.replace(/\d+/g, c => (c<10?'0':'') + +c)
);
```

PS

Safari also incorrectly treats 1991-01-01 as local, not UTC, so for users with a negative timezone offset (positive in EMCAScript) `new Date('1991-01-01')` returns a date for 1990-12-31. See [*Why does Date.parse give incorrect results?*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2587345/why-does-date-parse-give-incorrect-results)

If you really *must* use Date, then manually parse it as UTC and use *toISOString*. That avoids issues with the built–in parser and timezone offsets.

```js
// Change YYYY-M-D to YYYY-MM-DD
// Separator can be any non-digit character
function reformatDate(s) {
  let [y,m,d] = s.split(/\D/);
  return new Date(Date.UTC(y, m-1, d)).toISOString().slice(0,10);
}

console.log(reformatDate('1991-1-1'));
```

Comment: this case does not cover 
'1991-01-01'.split('-').map(c => (c<10?'0':'')+c).join('-')

Comment: reformate date is best way or ad extra condition of length digitg

Comment: '1991-01-01'.replace(/\d+/g, c => (c.length < 2 && c<10?'0':'')+c)

Comment: @PalaniichukDmytro—well spotted. Just convert *c* to number before adding: `'1991-01-01'.split('-').map(c => (c<10?'0':'')+ +c).join('-')`. :-)

Answer (score 0):

What about using moment.js?

```
const date = moment('1991-1-1').format('Y-MM-DD'); // 1991-01-01
```

Comment: I know moment, but it's a small app, and only one validation, I font want use library for one operation

Comment: what about overriding the locale options?

`const date = new Date('1991-1-1');`

`date.toLocaleDateString('en-US', {
  year: 'numeric',
  month: '2-digit',
  day: '2-digit',
});`

That will return something like '1991/01/01', then you just play with it, may be changing the '/' by '-'